# Json in Python: Receive/Check duplicate key error

Tags: python, json

The `json` module of python acts a little of the specification when having duplicate keys in a map:

```
import json
>>> json.loads('{"a": "First", "a": "Second"}')
{u'a': u'Second'}
```

I know that this behaviour is specified in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#repeated-names-within-an-object):

> The RFC specifies that the names within a JSON object should be
>   unique, but does not specify how repeated names in JSON objects should
>   be handled. By default, this module does not raise an exception;
>   instead, it ignores all but the last name-value pair for a given name:

**For my current project, I absolutely need to make sure that no duplicate keys are present in the file and receive an error/exception if this is the case? How can this be accomplished?**

I'm still stuck on Python 2.7, so a solution which also works with older versions would help me most.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you could try using the [`JSONDecoder`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) class and specifying a custom `object_pairs_hook`, which will receive the duplicates before they would get deduped.

```
import json

def dupe_checking_hook(pairs):
    result = dict()
    for key,val in pairs:
        if key in result:
            raise KeyError("Duplicate key specified: %s" % key)
        result[key] = val
    return result

decoder = json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=dupe_checking_hook)

# Raises a KeyError
some_json = decoder.decode('''{"a":"hi","a":"bye"}''')

# works
some_json = decoder.decode('''{"a":"hi","b":"bye"}''')
```

Comment: Thanks! Are there any possibilites to generated some context on the error message? For example the name of the map (if any) which contains the error?

Comment: Not easily, because the hook only gets the key-value pairs. (You could dump out the entire list, which would probably give you a good guess as to what it was based on the collection of values, but also might be rather large.)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will take any json that has repeated keys and put them into an array. for example takes this json string '''{"a":"hi","a":"bye"}''' and gives {"a":['hi','bye']} as output

```
import json
def dupe_checking_hook(pairs):
    result = dict()
    for key,val in pairs:
        if key in result:
            if(type(result[key]) == dict):
                temp = []
                temp.append(result[key])
                temp.append(val)
                result[key] = temp
            else:
                result[key].append(val)
        else:
            result[key] = val
    return result

decoder = json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=dupe_checking_hook)
#it will not raise error
some_json = decoder.decode('''{"a":"hi","a":"bye"}''')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. and how it solves the question. Thanks