# Data loss due to json stringifying dict keys

Tags: python, json

Consider the example below

```
>>> import json
>>> d = {0: 'potato', '0': 'spud'}
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"0": "potato", "0": "spud"}'
>>> json.loads(json.dumps(d))
{'0': 'spud'}
```

I'd prefer for this to raise exception.  In the docs there is a bit about `object_pairs_hook` kwarg for the deserialiser, but it would be better to fail early at the serialiser and not generate the "weird json" output in the first place.

Is there anything in the `json` builtin to help me, or any drop in replacement which is a bit more cautious with dicts?  I'd rather not have to extend `JSONEncoder` and pre-check every dict key if possible.

Comment: Related: [Json in Python: Receive/Check duplicate key error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16172011/json-in-python-receive-check-duplicate-key-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you stay with Python's `json` module, there's no way out (as you said you don't want any pre-checks of keys or customizing). But if things are going to stay inside Python, you can try the `demjson` library, for it seems to handle integer\string problem somehow. I haven't tried it myself, although.

Comment: It works.  `demjson.encode(d, strict=True)` raises `demjson.JSONEncodeError: ('object properties (dictionary keys) must be strings in strict JSON', 0)` and with `strict=False` you get `u'{0:"potato","0":"spud"}'` output.